# CSS nth-child issue

Tags: html, css

I need to write css only for `<span class="number">200</span>`, below I have given I used CSS code, but it not working,

Here is an example:

```css
.statistics-inner div.stat span.number:nth-child(3){
font-size: 38px!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="stat" data-count="1200">
<span class=""></span>
<span class="number">1200</span>
<span class="count-title">LINES OF CODES THIS MONTH</span>
</div>

<div class="stat" data-count="4800">
<span class=""></span>
<span class="number">4800</span>
<span class="count-title">TEST CASES WRITTEN</span>
</div>

<div class="stat" data-count="200">
<span class=""></span>
<span class="number">200</span>
<span class="count-title">INCREMENTAL RELEASE THIS YEAR</span>
</div>

<div class="stat" data-count="1000">
<span class=""></span>
<span class="number">1000</span>
<span class="count-title">COFFEE &amp; TEA CUPS</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You're looking for the third DIV not the third SPAN. `span.number` is **always** the **second** child.

Comment: Why not use an attribute selector? `[data-count="200"] .number { font-size: 38px; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nth-child(n)` needs to be added to `div.stat`:

```
.statistics-inner div.stat:nth-child(3) span.number {
    font-size: 38px!important;
}
```

**Edit:**

Also attribute selector if the `data-count` is static and not dynamic

```
.statistics-inner div.stat span.number[data-count="200"] {
    font-size: 38px!important;
}
```